# How can I make my own linux distro?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, linux-kernel

> **My question is bit off-topic or may be impractical.**

---

The thing is, on the web too many material available to download customized linux distro.
But what if I want to make my own linux distro ?

Lets say I have downloaded linux kernel, gnome dekstop, gnu grub. How can I build my own distro with help of these.

I want your help, reference, links.

Thank you.

Comment: I give you a +1, but I suggest to go with this question to unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 1):

[Linux From Scratch (LFS) is a project that provides you with step-by-step instructions for building your own custom Linux system, entirely from source code.](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/).

Comment: Hi @ThatGraemeGuy. I found this on web. But I want a tutorial like thing.

Comment: We really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Iain & Aditya, it simply isn't possible to distill the instructions involved in LFS in any meaningful way, it is a very complex undertaking.

Comment: @ThatGraemeGuy: That's why we have a too broad close reason.

Comment: My point is that complaining that there's not enough detail in the answer is meaningless, since there's no reasonable way to go into further detail.